# <on-start> Expression

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, spring-webflow

I am studying Spring WebFlow, and I am apparently missing a key concept of Spring in a sample application I am studying.  I have the following XML which gets the property ***allItems*** from a shopping cart.

```
<on-start>
    <evaluate expression="order.setBooksOrdered(shoppingCart.allItems)" />
</on-start>
```

However, I do not see a method or property by that name in the ShoppingCart class below.  Although of course there is a ***getAllITems()*** class.  It all compiles and works, but I am apparently missing a key concept here.

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class ShoppingCart implements Serializable {
    private List<Book> shopping = new ArrayList<Book>();

    public void addItem(Book newItem) {
        this.shopping.add(newItem);
    }

    public List<Book> getAllItems() {
        return shopping;
    }

    public void clear() {
        this.shopping.clear();
    }
}
```

Can someone point me in the direction of the key concept I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [JavaBean documentation](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Beans/beans02/).

If you have a JavaBean which has a JavaBean property, you access that property (in this case `allItems`) with a method `get<propertyName>` (in this case `getAllItems()`) or `is<propertyName>` when the property is a boolean.  The actual name of the field is irrelevant to the JavaBean standard.

There is more to the JavaBean specification than just that.  I recommend taking a look at the linked documentation.

So to access the `allItems` property of the `shoppingCart` bean, you will actually be triggering the `getAllItems()` method.